# Using Gson with multiple values for object

Tags: java, json, serialization, collections, gson

I have this Json code:

```
{
 "term" : {
   "PrincipalTranslations" : {
      "0" : {
            termine:"casa", 
            traduzione:"home"
            }
      "1" :{
             termine:"testa",
             traduzione:"head"
           }
       "2" :{
             termine:"dito",
             traduzione:"finger"
           }
   }
 }
}
```

How can I deserialize the object 0, 1, 2??
If instead of object 0, 1, 2 I wrote object "zero" (and stop), it works! 
I've used this implementation:

```
public class Item {    
        private term term;

        public term getTERM() {
                return term;
        }  
}

public class term {
       private PrincipalTranslations PrincipalTranslations;

        public PrincipalTranslations getPrincipalTranslations() {
                return PrincipalTranslations;
        }      
}

public class PrincipalTranslations {
        private zero zero;

        public zero getZero() {
                return zero;
        }
}

public class zero {
        private String termine;

        public String gettermine() {
                return termine;
        }
}
```

and use it so, it print (in the right way) "casa"

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileReader reader = new FileReader("/home/peppe/test_ff"); 

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        Item p = gson.fromJson(reader, Item.class);
        System.out.print(p.getTERM().getPrincipalTranslations().getZero().gettermine());


        reader.close();
      }
}
```

Comment: I think you have mistakes in your structures. As I understand PrincipalTranslations is contains an array of Items each one having 2 fields (termine and traduzione). If I'm right review your class declarations then I can post you some useful code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the object zero, than in your ’Principal Translations‘ class use the ’SerializedName’ annotation: http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html

It will look like this:

```
@SerializedName("0")
public Zero zero;
```